# Unable to find MonoDroid in my VS2010 Professional

Tags: c#, android, mono, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I've just registered my key to VS 2010 Professional, Mono for android has been already installed also, and done everything going through this tutorial: [this](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/installation/Installation_for_Windows)
But it seems that VS 2010 Pro "doesn't know" about MonoDroid has been already installed. Here's a proof for that:  http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/4971/89774099.png

I've already tried opening a new Mono for android application in MonoDevelop IDE and it seems to be alright, so what could be the problem that VS isn't aware of my MonoDroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two questions: First, you tried restarting VS since MonoDroid installation right? Second, was visual studio installed before or after installing MonoDroid?

Comment: Yes, I've just now restarted my computer and for the second question: VS was installed after installing MonoDroid

Comment: I'd say since visual studio was not on your computer at the time during the MonoDroid installation the VS plug-in was not installed. Try reinstalling MonoDroid now that you have visual studio installed.

Comment: I am sorry but I'm currently facing another problem: http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/2079/93297297.PNG

Comment: As you can see in the picture after I run the device the API doesn't see that the device is already running and therefore I can't test my application, do you know why?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, it's been a while since I've used monodroid. I'd suggest trying to create another emulator instance maybe and make sure you're starting the emulator after you've got your project open in visual studio.

Comment: Yeah, after asking you that I've been searching about it, I had to open the emulator in monodevelop project and then open VS and start my app, thank you again,.